# Is the choice of words appropriate ? Is the grammar right in the following statement?

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning

I hope you dont think any less of me because of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is beautifully correct.

The meaning is something like "I hope your opinion about me is not negatively impacted by this"